# Do these two integrals agree?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\tilde \Sigma$ be a $\sigma$  algebra on $S$ such that $\tilde \Sigma \subset \Sigma$.

Then, $(S,\tilde \Sigma,\mu)$ is a measure space in its own right.

Now, let $f$ be an integrable function with respect to $\Sigma$. Then, if $f$ is measurable with respect to $\tilde \Sigma$ and $A \in \tilde \Sigma$, then would the integral of $f$ over $A$ when the "ambient space" is $(S,\tilde \Sigma,\mu)$ be equal to the integral of $f$ over $A$ when the ambient space is $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the integral of a $\tilde{\Sigma}$ measurable function is the same whether the underlying $\sigma$-algebra is $\Sigma$ or $\tilde{\Sigma}$. For your particular case, consider integrating the $\tilde{\Sigma}$ measurable function $f \chi_A$ over all of $S$.

Or in short: yes.

Comment: But, isn't the set of $\tilde \Sigma$ measurable simple functions a "smaller" set than the set of $\Sigma$ measurable simple functions? So, wouldn't the "approximation" of the integral of a $\tilde \Sigma$ measuralbe function when the underlying $\sigma$ algebra is $\tilde \Sigma$ be smaller than when the underlying sigma algebra is $\Sigma$?

Comment: @hl0202 The same sequence of simple function approximations that you can use when the $\sigma$-algebra is $\tilde{\Sigma}$ work when the $\sigma$-algebra is $\Sigma$.

Comment: The sequence of simple function approximations when the $\sigma$-algebra is $\Sigma$ would not work when the $\sigma$-algebra is $\tilde \Sigma$, though. I mean, don't I have "more" simple functions when the $\sigma$ algebra is $\Sigma$?

Comment: so, for a positive $\tilde \Sigma$ measurable function $f$, wouldn't the approximation by simple function  over $\tilde \Sigma$ be smaller than the approximation over $\Sigma$?

Comment: @hl0202 There are more simple functions when the $\sigma$-algebra is $\Sigma$, but it doesn't matter: if you have a positive, $\tilde{\Sigma}$ measurable function, you can take an increasing sequence of $\tilde{\Sigma}$-simple functions, and it will converge to the $\Sigma$-integral of $f$.

Comment: Why is it going to converge to the $\Sigma$-integral of $f$??

Comment: @hl0202 There are lots of proofs. One is to note that you have a monotone sequence of $\Sigma$-measurable functions which converges pointwise a.e. to $f$. Another would use uniqueness of the Radon-Nikodym derivative. Plenty of other options exist.